# want to transfer data from sqlite database to server

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyKaD.png)I have developed an offline data entry app in android where the user enters all the details which will be saved in sqlite db.

At the end of the day I want to transfer data from the sqlite db to a server which stores the data in PostgreSQL db. I didn't find any good answer as per my requirement.

Comment: I do not see any good question.

Comment: what exactly is a problem? You can't read data from your SQLite? You can't send data to the server?

Comment: Actually i have to send  whole data from sqlite database to server

Comment: above code is used by me but i m getting issue on above code kindly help me

Comment: Please put all code in your post. As in comments its unreadable. And you are supposed to describe your problems in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /// whrite this in database class
   public Cursor getAllData(String emailid) {
            String query = "select * from "+ORDERHISTORY_TABLE+" Where "+ ACCOUNT + "= '"+ emailid +"' ORDER BY "+ NOTIFICATION_RID +" ASC ";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            return cursor;
        }
////write this in java class
                   {
     Cursor cursor = helpher.getAllData(Emailid);//cursor hold all your data
                    arr = new JSONArray();
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                        do {
                            jobj = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                jobj.put("Order_id", cursor.getString(1));
                                jobj.put("Order_tittle",  cursor.getString(2));
                                jobj.put("Order_quantity",  cursor.getString(3));
                                jobj.put("Order_price",  cursor.getString(5));
                                jobj.put("Order_totalprice",  cursor.getString(4));
                                jobj.put("Order_image",  cursor.getString(6));
                                jobj.put("Address1",  cursor.getString(8));
                                jobj.put("Address2",  cursor.getString(9));
                                jobj.put("Name",  cursor.getString(10));
                                jobj.put("Phone",  cursor.getString(11));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            arr.put(jobj);
                        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                    jobj = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jobj.put("data", arr);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String st = jobj.toString();
              Log.i("jhfg",""+st);




                    try {
                        JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest("url", new JSONObject(st),
                                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                        //Process os success response
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    // add the request object to the queue to be executed
    //                ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request_json);

            }
```